# loop populated with array only populating first element

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop through files (nodeListTxt is an array of filepaths) and grep the timestamp. However the all 4 timestamps seem to be populating the first element of the arrays instead of one element per timestamp. Furthermore  echo $iter only printed out 1 to the terminal which would indicate that the loop isnt working, if the grep statement didnt grab 4 timestamps. Not sure how to fix this

```
recieveTimes=()
sentTimes=()

printTestHeader "Trace Behavior"
for i in "${nodeListTxt[@]}"
do
    iter=$((iter + 1))
    echo $iter
    echoSleep 5
    recieveTimes[$iter]=$(grep  -m 1 '\"path\":' ${i}| sed 's/.*timestampUtc\"://g' | sed 's/,.*//g')
    sentTimes[$iter]=$(grep  -m 2 '\"path\":' ${i}| sed 's/.*timestampUtc\"://g' | sed 's/,.*//g')
done
```

echo

Comment: If it prints `1`, it means that you are entering the loop. If it only prints `1`, then it is doinf only a single loop... are you sure that the array contains an list of more than one element?

Comment: Can you show how `nodeListTxt` is populated? Both the `for` loop and `$iter` seem to work as expected

Comment: nodeListTxt it is a file array /opt/xyz/exp/output/1_2.txt /opt/xyz/exp/output/1_3.txt /opt/xyz/exp/output/1_4.txt